# Jsoup - French font parsed encoded value

Tags: java, html, jsoup, rtf

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();  
Elements e = doc.select("span");
for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
elements.add(e.get(i).html());
}
```

The above code parses french fonts from this **réhydraté,** to this `r&eacute;hydrat&eacute;`. I got issue to print this in the tool. I've planned to use `replace()` function but it won't be the proper way since there are a lot fonts having same issue. How do I solve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with fonts. It is showing the mapping of certain Unicode characters to HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's parsing it correctly and re-encoding it with HTML character codes, which would render properly when viewed by a browser.

A potentially unsafe method, depending on the way you're rendering your output, would be to change your [`Document.OutputSettings`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html)'s [`Entities.EscapeMode`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.EscapeMode.html) to `xhtml`.

I'd suggest reading the documentation on your output tool to see what kind of escape sequences it supports.

(By "rendering your output", I'm referring to how the output is viewed by the user in the end.  If it's going to be HTML viewed by a browser, your output with HTML entities, such as `&eacute;` will render properly as "é".)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain more when you **rendering your output**. As i know I did specify any render for out, I just using the default. Which documentation you are referring?